# Is there a way to dump all registered sidebar/widget?

Tags: custom-field, widgets, sidebar, child-pages, register-sidebar

I need to know the properties of sidebar and widgets I've added, is there a way to dump those? Thanks.

Comment: As you question was auto-flagged as _"low quality"_, I suggest you take the time to read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

There is, in fact! The global variable `$wp_registered_sidebars` stores the registered sidebars, and `$wp_registered_widgets` stores all registered widgets (by widget ID).

Comment: Thanks! How will I use it on the page? Thanks

Comment: @HML That's something you want to read up [on google](https://www.google.at/search?q=debugging+php&oq=debugging+php&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1440j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: @kaiser Is Austrian Google particularly good for looking stuff up on PHP debugging?

Comment: Austrian Quality. What else.

Comment: Was expecting to find only Kaiserschmarrn.